# How can put 0 in input when ngModel is null in Angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript

```
 <tr *ngFor="let item of capturaDiaria.inventarioList; let i = index">

  <td> <input type="number" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="item.kg_blanca" name="blanca-{{i}}"> </td>

</tr>
```

When the user enters for the first time, the list data is null and I need to show 0 in the input

Comment: How is `inventarioList` when the component is loaded? Are there any elements within the array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can:

1. initialize `item.kg_blanca` in `ngOnInit()`

or

2. Create custom pipe in view that updates value

I would initialize value on start. If you were using one way data binding, getter would be good solution as well.

Comment: the option 2, it can use in input?

Comment: yes, if to split it  on one way data binding. If you use 2-way data binding - the value should be the same in component and view: either null or 0, but not both

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize it at ngOnInit() or better yet, you can change...

`[(ngModel)]="item.kg_blanca"`

to this...

`[(ngModel)]="item.kg_blanca !== null ? item.kg_blanca : '0"`

this way if it comes through null, the input field uses 0 instead of null