# If ngModel value is null then set value=0

Tags: html, angular, primeng

I want to set the value as 0 when the value is null. Currently, I'm using angular primeng materials.

```
<p-calendar [(ngModel)]="model.start_time" [timeOnly]="true" placeholder="00:00"></p-calendar>
```

I want to set minutes' default value as 0.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can put 0 in input when ngModel is null in Angular 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58122177/how-can-put-0-in-input-when-ngmodel-is-null-in-angular-6)

Comment: It should set null when the user does not input @Alex_Yu

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

In this matter, we can give value to the ngModel. So we have to use the .ts file to set the value to the ngModel.

.ts

```
export class classComponent{
   this.model.start_time = 0;
}
```